# Convert a list of strings of lists to a list of integers

Tags: java, arrays, java-stream

is there a smart way to convert a list of strings of list into a list of integer list?

I have this List:

```
["0,0,0,0", "1,1,1,1"]
```

and I would like to get:

```
 [[0,0,0,0],[1,1,1,1]]
```

I have tried this:

```
String comma = ",";
List<String> coords = Arrays.asList("0,0,0,0","1,1,1,1");
List<Integer> coordList =  Arrays.asList(coords.get(0).split(comma)).stream()
                                    .map(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: If these represent a coordinate of some type, you should also be defining a class `Coordinate` to hold the related numbers. If you explain the meaning of the data, we could show that process as well. Do you have pairs such as 0-1, 0-1 as each coordinate, or is the set of four a coordinate where one coordinate is 0-0-0-0 and another coordinate is 1-1-1-1?

Comment: I just called it coordinate for giving an idea of data, but aren't coordinate in real, but thanks for the advice!

Comment: Use flatmap for ease

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking to:

```
List<List<Integer>> coordList = coords.stream()
        .map(s -> Arrays.stream(s.split(comma))
                .map(Integer::valueOf)
                .collect(Collectors.toList()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or much better is to create a method and call it in map:

```
private List<Integer> convertStringToIntegers(String s) {
    String comma = ",";
    return Arrays.stream(s.split(comma))
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

then:

```
List<List<Integer>> coordList = coords.stream()
        .map(this::convertStringToIntegers)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Outputs**

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1, 1]]
```